# Fields in Active Directory and Active Directory LDS

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-membership, schema, adam, adlds

Is there a definite source i can rely on to know the Objects, Fields that the `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` requires in Active Directory or Active Directory LDS. It is tiresome to go through all the fields in the active directory to know which ones are getting modified by the Asp.net Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx

There you will see a table with the property and the default directory attribute.